# Unity3D Web player - Not loading, white screen with unity logo

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine

I have build my unity project as Web Build. I put the HTML code generated in the project's .html file in my own page and copied the .unity3d file into the same directory.

Now when I launch the webpage I get a white screen with the unity logo where it would normally load (display a progressbar). For the record: I use visual Studio 2013 in which I have this webpage, and I use localhost to display all the pages (the default webserver for VS).

On internet explorer it says it failed to download the data file.
I tried multiple solutions such as adding a reference to a mime type in a custom web.config in the same directory as the html and .unity3d files. Did not work.

[image: Screen]

Comment: If you dig into the HTML file, what path is set for the `.unity3d` file? And what happens if you point your web browser at that path directly?

Comment: I'll get a 404 page error. The path is just the unity3d file, as both html and unity3d files are in the same dir.

Comment: If you get a 404 error trying to access the file, that seems to pretty strongly indicate it's not at that path.

Comment: How do you host your web build?

Comment: I just launch the website using Visual Studio's build in function.